# Windows Application Packaging Project - how to create folders

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm looking at migrating a .jsproj based Desktop Bridge installer to use .wapproj, one of the things my project does is deploy files in sub-directories of the install directory.

How do I replicate this in a .wapproj file?

Mike

Comment: Why you need to add files manually? After you referenced your project that needed converted, when running the app, any files missed or any exceptions you got? If I misunderstand you please provide more details. Include details about your original JS project, what you have already done, what actual issue you are meeting and so on.

Comment: for historical reasons, the app is built to load some of its functionality from an Extensions\<dllname> directory. From my understanding of the current packaging/store functionality - we can't do full "in app" loads of the DLLs using the store/extensions API at the moment and we would require to be able to make an app that by default installed a load of extensions at the same time.

Comment: I'm still confused about your issue. Please check my comment again. After you referenced your project that needed converted, when running the app, any files missed or any exceptions you got? Include details about your original JS project, what you have already done, what actual issue you are meeting and so on. How you load the extensions currently, what are these extensions for .Provide information as much as possible please.Otherwise we cannot help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the folder in the application's project (not the packaging project), add the files as content and set them to "Copy to output". Then when you create and deploy the package, the folder and the content will be part of resulting package, at the right relative location.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to define the destination folder, for example common application data folder?